# Taskset does not Work Properly

Tags: bash, cpu

When I type the command

```
top
```

The first row of the output is

```
29646 Usernam+  20   0 7041320 1.047g 105604 S  1267  0.6 256:11.86 MATLAB
```

As you can see, the CPU utilization is 1267%. That means, this process is using 13 CPU of the server. By the following command, I try to force this process to use only one CPU (The 30th CPU of server)

```
taskset -c -p 30 29646
```

However, I still see the CPU utilization of the process is about 1300%. Why taskset is not working properly?

Comment: Isn't this a problem for [Unix.se]?

Comment: The operating system is Linux

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an arguments misplacing. Try

```
taskset -c 30 -p <pid>
```

Comment: G:  The command that you suggested does not work on my machine which is a Centos Linux. By using the "taskset" command in the way I previously indicated, I get a confirmation message from taskset indicating that the affinity of process is changed. However, "ps" command, I can see that taskset is not working properly and does have any effect on the CPU assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
taskset -a -c -p 30 29646
```

From the [man page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html):

> -a, --all-tasks
>
> Set or retrieve the CPU affinity of all the tasks (threads) for a given PID.